# Migrating spring-cloud-aws-messaging to new Spring

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I need to migrate `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` to another compatible lib with new Spring Version.

Because the last version of `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` has `javax.servlet » javax.servlet-api` as Provided Dependencies (1), and the new Spring Version uses Jakarta instead of Javax.

(1) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.awspring.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/2.4.4

Another problem is that I have the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/PayloadArgumentResolver
    at io.awspring.cloud.messaging.listener.QueueMessageHandler.initArgumentResolvers(QueueMessageHandler.java:118)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:237)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 161 more
```

Because `PayloadArgumentResolver` class was removed from Spring and `QueueMessageHandler` class tried to use It.

I tried to use this two libs, but It didnt work:

```
<artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter-sns</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-sqs</artifactId>
```

Comment: If you want to write a Java app that invokes AWS SQS, then look at using the official AWS SQS Java API.  A benefit of using the AWS Java SDK is you get support you do not get from using a 3rd party API . See: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sqs/SqsClient.html

Comment: Version 3.0.1. see https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/3.0.1/reference/html/index.html Spring Cloud AWS uses the AWS Java sdk